# TerminationProtected flag ignored for EMR cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-emr

I am setting up EMR cluster using CloudFormation template. Even though, I am passing `TerminationProtected: false` cluster is still created with termination protection turned on. Is this possible that the global company policy is overwriting this value? Here's a snippet of my YAML template

```
Type: AWS::EMR::Cluster
Properties:
  Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-cluster
  Applications:
    - Name: Hadoop
    - Name: ZooKeeper
    - Name: Spark
    - Name: Ganglia
  Instances:
    MasterInstanceGroup:
      ...
    CoreInstanceGroup:
      ...
    Ec2SubnetId: ...
    Ec2KeyName: ...
    TerminationProtected: False
    AdditionalMasterSecurityGroups:
      - ...
  BootstrapActions:
    - ...
  JobFlowRole : ...
  LogUri: ...
  ServiceRole : ...      
  ReleaseLabel: ...
  VisibleToAllUsers: ...
  Configurations:
    - Classification: hdfs-site
      ConfigurationProperties:
        dfs.replication: '2'
```

Comment: Is `TerminationProtected` a child of `Instances` or, when trying to condense the template for the purpose of presenting it here, you mistakenly changed the structure?

Comment: it is, and it seems it should be there: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticmapreduce-cluster.html

Comment: Could it be that it has to be `false` instead of `False`?

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari already tried that :( I will try running with non-boolean value, shouldn't CloudWatch throw an exception while seeing that?

Comment: Could you try `'false'` with the quotes.